# No module named 'scapy'. Kali and Python 2.6

Tags: python, pycharm, scapy

I think I made a mistake.

I'm using Kali and Python 2.6. And my scapy work well at first.

A few minutes ago, I tried to type "pip3 install scapy-python3"( I know I shouldn't use pip3 but I didn't know at first), but I just type wrong with "pip". The installation was successful but after that I'm not able to get access to scapy. When I import scapy, it will always come up a error.

I tried google the way to uninstall scapy and reinstall it. I used "apt-get remove python-scapy" to uninstall scapy
. After that I use "apt-get install kali-linux-full" to reinstall everything including scapy.

Also I tried to install python3.6 to run it but issue is still there.

My code:

```
#!usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy
```

Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1664, in main()
File "/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
File "/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) # execute the script
File "/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "/root/PycharmProjects/network_scanner/network_scanner.py", line 3, in 
import scapy.all as scapy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy'
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use Python 2.6? Because that's ancient, and unsupported these days.

Comment: If you have Python 3.6 (3.7 is even available these days), and you're happy to use version 3.6, try with `python3.6 -m pip install scapy-python3`.

Comment: @9769953 hi, thank for your reply. it's fine for me to use python2 or 3. I'm happy to use pyhton3 if it works. I tried python3 but it doesn't work.

Comment: Note that [Scapy itself reports to be Python 3 compatible](https://github.com/secdev/scapy), so `python3.6 -m pip install scapy` should be enough.

Comment: " it doesn't work." is not really helpful. Did you install things they way I suggested? If so, what error did you get?

Comment: @9769953 sorry I didn't make it clear. I tried typing "python3.6 ....scapy-python3/scapy" but "No module named 'scapy'" is still showing. I already installed python3.6.6. It's working but the issue keep sticking.

Comment: What *exactly* did you type? "python3.6 ....scapy-python3/scapy" is not exact. I have not suggested anything ending with "scapy-python3/scapy" either.

Comment: @9769953 I should say "python3.6 -m pip install scapy" and "python3.6 -m pip install scapy-python3"

Comment: @9769953 I found something new. The "lib/python3.6/site-packages" folder inside the project doesn't have a scapy package, so I copy one scapy package into the "lib/python3.6/site-packages". Then the issue fix. But when I created a new project and import the scapy, the issue comes again. I have check the "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages", there are "scapy", "scapy-2.4.0.dist-info" and scapy_python3-0.25.dist-info" which mean I really have scapy package, but the pytcharm seem not able to access them.

Comment: Don’t mistake scapy and scapy-python3 ! The second one is deprecated and won’t be updated

Comment: @Cukic0d Thanks for reminding me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Apt to remove something which wasn't installed with Apt. You can `pip3 install` the package and it should Just Work; though you could also optionally `pip uninstall` the package if you don't want it to be available to Python 2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. 

I installed python3.6.6. Also I  installed the scapy-python3 and scapy, but unfortunately the issue "No module named 'scapy" is still there.

It's a bit confused that when i typed "pip remove scapy" the command showed me "ERROR: unknown command "remove"

Comment: Sorry, that should be `pip uninstall`. Updated the post.

Comment: No worry. I follow the step and type "pip uninstall scapy" but it comes out a result "Not uninstalling scapy at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr"

Comment: I found something new. The "lib/python3.6/site-packages" folder inside the project doesn't have a scapy package, so I copy one scapy package into the "lib/python3.6/site-packages". Then the issue fix. But when I created a new project and import the scapy, the issue comes again. I have check the "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages", there are "scapy", "scapy-2.4.0.dist-info" and scapy_python3-0.25.dist-info" which mean I really have scapy package, but the pytcharm seem not able to access them

Comment: If you have a virtualenv, that's a significant factor which you should have mentioned in the question in the first place. On the other hand, scrapping the old env and starting over should be very straightforward. But please stop bypassing the tools with manual hacks; you are only making it harder for others to help you.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that. I will make a better question next time. But still thanks for your patient to help me, and I will remember not to manually change thing before it is fixed. I will go and reinstall the virtualenv. Thank you.

Comment: The fact that you are apparently trying unabashedly to use Kali as a development platform might also mean something... See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: You mean penetration test? Honestly I'm having a online course which tech penetration test and Kali is what they recommend to set up the lab. I read the post, agree to what he ask "why is so hard to use" ha but still want to learn more even it's hard. Pretty agree to the answer "This is a distribution for computer labs, virtual machines, and self contained boot cds/usbs." haha.

Comment: I mean quite frankly many people won't even read your question.

Comment: Got it because it is recommended for professional. Thanks for telling me that!

Comment: It is only recommended strictly for penetration testing. Read the link I posted.

Comment: I did but I don't get it why people won't even read it just because it's a penetration testing system? Sorry I'm new in area.

Comment: Discussing this here in comments is increasingly misdirected; perhaps post a follow-up question on [unix.se]. In brief, programming and general-computing questions tend to come from people who have no idea what they are doing, and are clearly not very successful when it comes to understanding written documentation. Much of this is phrased more politely between the lines in the linked post.